# Create Component with Lightning Admin Dialog box

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm not sure what its called but I'm looking to write a Lightning Component which utilizes the below image's section of Lightning App Builder. Does anyone know what its called? Doesn't have to be rich text, a simple text box in that section would do just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is outlined in [Configure Components for Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm). Basically, you add a "design" resource, which allows developers to expose text boxes, Boolean values, and picklists to administrators for customization. You can read more about that in [Aura Component Bundle Design Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm).